# Javascript - refer to outter object from inner array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The drinks: reference inside the object of the array passengers is not retrieving the ticket: value. How do I refer to the outer objects ticket value from inside the array?

```
var passengers = [ { name: 'Jane Doloop', paid: true, ticket: 'coach', drinks: [ticketDrinks(this.ticket, 0), ticketDrinks(this.ticket, 1)] },
                   { name: 'Dr.Evel', paid: true, ticket: 'firstclass' },
                   { name: 'Sue Property', paid: false, ticket: 'firstclass' },
                   { name: 'John Funcall', paid: true, ticket: 'coach' } ];




function ticketDrinks(ticket, location1) {
    console.log(ticket, location1);
    if (ticket == 'firstclass') {
        drink1 = 'cola';
        drink2 = 'water';
        if (location1 == 0) {
            return drink1;
        } else {
            return drink2;
        }

    } else if (ticket == 'coach') {
        drink1 = 'wine';
        drink2 = 'champagne';
        if (location1 == 0) {
            return drink1;
        } else {
            return drink2;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The linked question is for object initializers, but it's the same answer for array initializers (JavaScript arrays are, after all, just a special case of objects).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
{
    name: 'Jane Doloop',
    paid: true,
    ticket: 'coach',
    drinks: [ticketDrinks(this.ticket, 0), ticketDrinks(this.ticket, 1)]
}
```

You can do:

```
{
    name: 'Jane Doloop',
    paid: true,
    ticket: 'coach',
    drinks: [0, 1]
}
```

Then make [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to iterate over the array of objects and dynamically access to the property `tikets`.

And than, you make another [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to call the method `ticketDrinks()` passing the current object property `drinks`.

Code:

```js
var passengers = [{name: 'Jane Doloop',paid: true,ticket: 'coach',drinks: [0, 1]},{name: 'Dr.Evel',paid: true,ticket: 'firstclass'},{name: 'Sue Property',paid: false,ticket: 'firstclass'},{name: 'John Funcall',paid: true,ticket: 'coach'}],
    ticketDrinks = function (ticket, location1) {
      console.log(ticket, location1);
      var drink1, drink2;
      if (ticket === 'firstclass') {
        drink1 = 'cola';
        drink2 = 'water';
        return location1 === 0 ? drink1 : drink2;
      } else if (ticket === 'coach') {
        drink1 = 'wine';
        drink2 = 'champagne';
        return location1 === 0 ? drink1 : drink2;
      }
      return null;
    },
    result = passengers.map(function (user) {
      if (user.drinks) {
        user.drinks = user.drinks.map(function (location) {
          return ticketDrinks(user.ticket, location)
        });
      }

      return user;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```